# MatDatepicker can only be associated with a single input

Tags: html, angular, datepicker

I'm trying to use the **Datepicker feature of Angular Material** and got this error inside the "div" I created. **"Error: A MatDatepicker can only be associated with a single input."** After getting this error, I saw that when I select the dates, I cannot affect the following. I was only able to change the date area above.

You can see the feature I'm trying to use here:
[calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4eeL.png)

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-2">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="margin-0">
                <mat-label>{{ "PROD_REPORT.FROM" | translate }}</mat-label>
                <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="start_time" />
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="margin-0">
                <mat-label>{{ "PROD_REPORT.TO" | translate }}</mat-label>
                <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="end_time" />
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue, Actually when you use Angular material date picker multiple fields in the same form, then you should use #picker name should be different.

```
   <div class="col-2">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="margin-0">
            <mat-label>{{ "PROD_REPORT.FROM" | translate }}</mat-label>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="start_time" />
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="margin-0">
            <mat-label>{{ "PROD_REPORT.TO" | translate }}</mat-label>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker_another" [(ngModel)]="end_time" />
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker_another"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker_another></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```